# After restarting all of Hyperledger Fabric (V1.0) docker containers, how can I restart the container for chaincode?

Tags: docker, restart, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-container

I would like to know how to restart the container for chaincode, after restarting all of HLF docker containers, like orderer, peers, docker cli... I found the issue, "Chaincode should be re-deployed after restarting peer node" which was reported at HLF V0.6. Please refer to the following site.

https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/1655

Is it also true at HLF V1.0 ?

Comment: I think that you should re-instantiate the chaincode. Did you do this?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I restarted docker containers of HLF and issued "peer chaincode query" command via docker cli container, then chaincode container successfully restarted.